# best date time mysql format for jalali calendar

Tags: php, mysql

Hello in iran we use jalali calendar like `1399-06-30 12:12:50` and i want to save this date in mysql with laravel.

also you should know `DATETIME` mysql column format is not good for this. because for example in February we have 30 day but in jalali we have 31 day and this way not working properly;

I thinking and find some way to do this but i don`t know which this ways is better than another.

1- create varchar column and save data like the same

2- create integer column and save data like this `13990630121250` and when getting data convert to `1399-06-30 12:12:50` with php

3- create integer column and save data with the timestamp  `1496557661` and when getting data convert to `1399-06-30 12:12:50` with php

appreciate your guiding me regarding this.

Comment: I can advice combination of 4 fields `Year`, `Month`, `Day` and `Time`

Comment: I would store the date using the regular Gregorian date data type, and handle any conversion in application code.

Comment: in my program need using the date and time in many where and this increase background processing of server for